# Scaling SVG image but not the mask

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to render a image where the bottom part is cut of stylishly. The image should scale and fill the container so it is always 100% wide, but remains 500px high.

The current state almost works, however I do not want the mask to scale on the y-axis as it does now. The mask should stay a fixed height and only scale on the x-axis. The effect right now is that the mask cuts of a way to big piece of the image in large formats.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax slice" width="100%" height="500px">
  <defs>
    <mask id="clip">
      <path d="M0,45 100,40 100,0 0,0Z" fill="white"></path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://placeimg.com/1500/500/animals" mask="url(#clip)" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"></image></svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not very explicit about how you want the mask to behave when the image gets wider.

Here's one solution. Is this what you wanted?  The mask angles from full height on the left, to 90% height on the right. No matter how wide the image is.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="500px">
  <defs>
    <mask id="clip" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M0,1 1,0.9 1,0 0,0Z" fill="white"></path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://placeimg.com/1500/500/animals"
         width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" mask="url(#clip)"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hey.As you got mobile dev background too.Can you correct my approach too.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103447/make-svg-content-scaletofill-compatible-while-conserving-its-ratio/69104144?noredirect=1#comment122143571_69104144